# Работа с this в js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как организовать работу this относительно выбранной области?
(По аналогии с css)
css: .класс:hover .класс

При наводке на один класс изменится другой.  Хотел бы реализовать аналогию.

То есть, допустим у меня есть header в html. В нем есть тег li(не один, генерируется сразу после ввода данных и узнать его длину остаётся невозможным.) Хочу сделать возможным использование drag&drop, для изменения внешнего вида под посетителя. Проблема возникает как раз с определением созданых тегов. Как можно решить проблему? Задать всем тегам li один стиль? И  уже опираясь на это  строить свой код? Жду ваши предложения для постройки велосипеда. (Хотелось бы именно использовать this для этой задачи, но вот как использовать его тут правильно ума не предположу)

Comment: Некорректно поставлен вопрос.. Привязываетесь к какому-то this непонятному.. _Проблема возникает как раз с определением созданых тегов._ какая проблема? Добавьте код со своей "проблемой"

Comment: К сожалению сейчас не дома, скинуть свой пример не получится. Но суть в том, что есть органайзер который сохраняет записи из textarea, и сразу добавляет его в область в виде текста. Хотелось бы сделать возможность перетаскивать созданые записи в другие области(но использовать конкретно контекст this, и чтобы this работал в одной области,  а не был привязан к определённому объекту)

Comment: Что мешает привязать его к блоку? Аля, привязал к body и перетаскивай куда угодно в пределах body

Comment: Ничего не мешает, но мне хочется использовать именно this. Мне просто хочется узнать как ограничить область видимости для this. В пределах блока

Comment: Возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: Можно ли использовать prototype?

Comment: Использовать можно, но настоятельно рекомендую не заниматься подобным, по [давно известным причинам](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)

Comment: "- Mожно ли использовать микроскоп, чтобы забить гвоздь?" "- Mожно."

Answer (score 1):

```js
const mouseTarget = document.querySelector('.mouse');
const events = ['mouseenter', 'mouseleave'];

for (let evt of events) {
  mouseTarget.addEventListener(evt, e => {
    e.target.classList.toggle('hovered');
    e.target.querySelector('.inner').classList.toggle('dark');
  });
}
```

```css
.mouse {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.mouse.hovered {
  background-color: red;  
}

.inner.dark {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class='mouse'>
  <div class='inner'></div>
</div>
```